# Defining a measure and showing it's a sum of two measures.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\mu$ be a measure. Define $\mu_0(E)=\operatorname{Sup}\{\mu(F):F\subset E, \mu(F)<\infty\}$. Show that there exists a measure $\mu_1$ s.t $\mu=\mu_0+\mu_1$ Hint: Define $\mu_1$ to be $0$ on every $\sigma$-finite set $E$.

So I defined $\mu_1(E)$ to be $0$ is $E$ is $\sigma$-finite and $\infty$ otherwise. This works, up to the fact that I couldn't prove that $\mu_1$ is indeed a measure. Let $\{A_i\}$ be disjoint $\sigma$-finite sets. How do I prove that $\mu_1(\bigcap_{i}A_i)=\sum_{i}\mu_1(A_i)=0$?

I couldn't show that a union of $\sigma$ finite sets is $\sigma$ finite and I also believe it's not true. But still this is the hint.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(A_i)$ be countably many disjoint $\sigma$-finite sets. Then there are sets $A_{ij}$  of finite measure ($\mu(A_{ij})=0$) such that $A_i = \cup_j A_{ij}$.

Now we need to define an increasing sequence of sets of finite measure out of these many sets. We do some diagonal approach (like Cantor's diagonal argument):

Define
$$
B_i = \cup_{j=1}^i A_{j,i+1-j}.
$$
Then these sets are increasing $B_i \subset B_{i+1}$ and have finite measure.
In addition, $\cup B_i = \cup A_i$. Hence that set is $\sigma$-finite.